# server request method using vb,net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how would i be able to achive something like php's

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
```

using vb.net - im trying to prevent people from accessing a webpage unless they are directed there by a form post.

Thank you

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496)

Answer (score 3):

[The `HttpRequest` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) has [a `HttpMethod` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) which would indicate this.  This object can be accessed by the `Request` property available on the base `Page` class (so from any page).

It's worth noting that this isn't a way to "secure" a page.  Anybody can make a POST request, they don't need to have been "directed there by a form."